# JS Promises returns

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm developing with the JS promises and I have a doubt, I have readed a lot of answers but I have not yet understood what's the difference between the following code lines. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

```
// Case 1
firstPromise()
  .then(() => {
    return secondPromise();
  })
  .then()...

// Case 2
firstPromise()
  .then(() => {
    secondPromise();
  })
  .then()...
```

In the first case, it return the second promise, in the second case it just execute. What's the result in the flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first makes the result of the first `then` depend on what happens with `secondPromise`, the second does not.

`then` creates a new promise. That promise will be resolved/rejected based on the return value of the `then` callback:

- If `then` returns a *thenable* value (such as another promise), `then`'s promise is *resolved to* that thenable and either fulfills when that thenable fulfills or rejects when that thenable rejects.
- If the `then` callback returns a non-thenable value, the promise is fulfilled with that value.

*(If the term "thenable" isn't familiar, or you're not clear on the distinction between "fulfill" and "resolve," I go into promise terminology in [this post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/) on my blog.)*

In your first example, the `then` callback returns the second promise, so its promise is resolved to `secondPromise`'s promise. In your second example, you're not returning anything, so the result of calling the `then` callback is the value `undefined`, so `then`'s promise is fulfilled with the value `undefined`.

Comment: Clarification for OP: Note that `() => 1` and `() => { return 1 }` return both `1`, but `() => { 1 }` does not.

Comment: @Amadan: From the content of the question, it seems clear the OP knows that: *"In the first case, it return the second promise, in the second case it just execute."* (Others, though, may need reminding.)

Comment: Thanks guys, now I have undestood.
So, It's good practice to use `return secondPromise();` or `() => secondPromise()`, correct?

Comment: `good practice` - I'd say **mandatory practice** if you want the promise chain to wait for `secondPromise` to resolve :p

Comment: `so then's promise is resolved with the value undefined` immediately without any regard for the promise returned by `secondPromise()` i.e. the code in `secondPromise` could take a week, but the next `.then` will be fired ASAP

Comment: @LucaM: It depends entirely on what you want to achieve. If you want `secondPromise` to have an effect on the chain, you must return it. If you don't, you must not. :-) As JaromandaX points out, if you don't, then `secondPromise` is separate from and parallel with the chain.